# incorrect subtraction in R

Tags: r

I want create new variable by subtraction

```
EA$SalesBefore <- sail$sum1 - EA$ActionEffect
```

but sometimes `sail$sum1` can be less than 0. For example,

```
sail$sum1 = 90
EA$ActionEffect = -24
```

Now it calculates 90 - -24, i.e. 90 + 24 = 114, but I need 90 - 24 = 66.

How to do that if `sail$sum1 < 0`, then subtract without -- (two minuses), just one 90 - sum1?

Comment: this is not *incorrect subtraction in R* - this is how subtraction works.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper sail$sum1 - EA$ActionEffect  =90--24. i did typo. Fixed my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can wrap with `abs` and then use `-`

```
sail$sum1- abs(EA$ActionEffect)
```